# Store bought Frozen Chicken Breast inc added water

Tags: oven, frozen, chicken-breast

I bought the above and the package says 'oven cook from frozen, if allowed to defrost reduce cooking time accordingly'.

If allowed to defrost safely, can I shallow fry it in a wok, or HAS it got to be oven cooked?

Answer (score 1):

You can cook it however you like, it's meat. I would suggest slicing it up and stir frying it if you are using a wok. If you want to keep it whole, use a frying pan with a thicker base and place a heavyish lid on top of the breast with a piece of baking paper between the two to even out the thickness of the piece of meat. That will help it to cook more evenly.

Comment: It's just that I did that at the weekend and had a real upset stomach, so if I was happy I cooked it well enough, it would have probably been nothing to do with the Chicken?

Comment: Hard to say. The main thing is ensuring the chicken is at a safe temperature for as long as possible. It must be defrosted quickly - meat should not be left at room temperature for more than 2 hours _throughout its 'life'_. So defrosting it on the kitchen counter overnight is a big no-no. It should either be defrosted in the fridge overnight, or defrosted under _cold_ running water as quickly as possible. When cooking it should reach 75º in the centre and stay there for 10 minutes. This naturally is of utmost importance when cooking from frozen. Invest a tenner in a digital probe thermometer.

Comment: People love to make conjectures about what caused them an upset stomach, but they are usually wrong. First, they tend to blame the last meal or two, but food poisoning can have an incubation time of up to 72 hours. Second, half the time an upset stomach is caused by a virus and not a foodborne bacteria. So, stop thinking about "I had an upset stomach, what should I do differently" and simply learn basic food safety. Our tag info is a good place to start, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info

Answer (score 0):

Cooking chicken from frozen isn't a great idea because you'll have to overcook the outside in order to cook the inside. If you were to cook from frozen oven cooking is one safe possibility, which is why the instructions say to do that - it's for the avoidance of lawsuits. Thawed you can cook it any way you like, there's no limitation on method just because it was once frozen.